# Google Sheets -- Return the smallest string shared by two text cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column in my Google Sheet where all cells will share most, but not all, of their text. For example:

```
Column A
Test_Monday_iOS
Test_Monday_iOS
Test_Monday_iOS
Test_Monday_Android
Test_Monday_Android
Test_Monday_Android
```

And I want to return the minimum consecutive string shared by all cells:

```
Column A.             Column B
Test_Monday_iOS       Test_Monday_
Test_Monday_iOS
Test_Monday_iOS
Test_Monday_Android
Test_Monday_Android
Test_Monday_Android
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach. Its currently tested to figure out the terms that could originate from* `left`/`right`/`middle` (as in screenshot)

```js
=let(Σ,A1, Λ,tocol(reduce(,sequence(len(Σ)),lambda(a,c,{a;index(mid(Σ,c,sequence(len(Σ)-c+1)))})),1),
     +sort(filter({Λ,len(Λ)},countif(A:A,"*"&Λ&"*")=counta(A:A)),2,))
```

[image]